# Error in ASP.NET MVC file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Look, guys. I am trying to upload some info, but can not load file. Just check the code: 
View:

```
<form method="post" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
        <div class="not-that-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Photo">Photo</label>
                <input type="file"
                       id="Photo"
                       name="Photo"
                       accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"
                       onchange="show(this)" />
            </div>

            <img id="onLoad"
                 src="#"
                 alt="photo is optional">
        </div>...........some another info.
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(InventorViewModel inventor)
{
    inventor.Photo = Request.Files["Photo"];
    InventorEntity onAdding = new InventorEntity()
    {
        FirstName = inventor.FirstName,
        SurName = inventor.SurName,
        DateOfBirth = inventor.DateOfBirth,
        Sex = inventor.Sex,
        HigherEducation = inventor.HigherEducation == "on" ? true : false,
        Description = inventor.Description,
        Country = uow.UserBL.GetCounryById(int.Parse(inventor.Country)),
        Photo = ImageConvertor.ConvertToBytes(inventor.Photo)
    };
    uow.UserBL.CreateInventor(onAdding);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

so and when i add this model to database, the photo is NULL. Any ideas? Maybe i should change something (or everything xD)

Comment: Shouldn't the tag enctype="multipart/form-data" be in the form tag?

Comment: yes! finally, thanks man)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` to the form and change the controller code to this

```
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
 {
     var file = Request.Files[0];

     if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        // do what you want to do
     }
 }
```

you can also make the file as part of the view model by adding `HttpPostedFileBase`. Model binder will bind the file to that property.

`public HttpPostedFileBase attachment { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.